# How can I have un-ordered div with different height floating left?

Tags: css, html

I would like to have a div which contains 4 columns inside it.

Where as each column will have a div with its contents (Where as some contents are huge and some are lesser).

Instead of me explaining it please have a look at this image:

[image: http://m-suresh.com/projects/images/div.jpg])

And kindly help me in achieving this layout.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you post some code that you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have idea from this:

```css
.body {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.mainColumn {
  width: 840px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.mainColumn ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.mainColumn ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
  float: left;
}

.colone {
  margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
  background: #CCCCCC;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="mainColumn">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="colone">
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</p>
        </div>
        <div class="colone">
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has
            been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
        </div>
        <div class="colone">
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since</p>
        </div>

      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="colone">
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has
            been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="colone">
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has
            been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
        </div>
        <div class="colone">
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="colone">
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy
            text ever since the 1500s</p>
        </div>
        <div class="colone">
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has
            been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
        </div>
        <div class="colone">
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since typesetting industry.
            Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since</p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="colone">
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy </p>
        </div>
        <div class="colone">
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has
            been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
            text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
        </div>
        <div class="colone">
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since Lorem Ipsum is simply
            dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever sinceLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
            and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since</p>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on what your needs are, does the content need to flow over to adjacent columns like the image, or do you have 4 column divs with static content?

Assuming the latter, you could make the column div's behave like table-cells: http://jsfiddle.net/wy4GR/

Answer (score 0):

HTML Code:

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="columns">       
         <div class="innerDiv">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
        </div>
        <div class="innerDiv">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="columns">       
         <div class="innerDiv">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
        </div>
        <div class="innerDiv">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="columns">       
         <div class="innerDiv">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
        </div>
        <div class="innerDiv">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="columns">       
         <div class="innerDiv">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
        </div>
        <div class="innerDiv">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
#main {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.columns {
    width: 21%;
    height: auto;
    float:left;
    margin: 1%;
}

.innerDiv {
    width: auto;
    background-color: #ccc;
    flot: left;
    margin:10px 0 0 0;
 }
```

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GVLNW/1/